# Mongo replace causing duplicates in sub documents c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
interface Nameable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Parent : Nameable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}

class Child
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public string DataOne { get; set; }

    public string DataTwo { get; set; }

    public double DataThree { get; set; }
}



    static async void MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(10000, 50000); i++)
        {
            Parents.Add(CreateParent());
        }

        Parents = Parents.GroupBy(g => g.Name).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();

        foreach (var parent in Parents)
        {
            await Insert<Parent>(parent);
        }

        // update objects randomly;

        foreach (var parent in Parents)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(10, 30); i++)
            {
                int decision = random.Next(0, 2);

                if (decision == 0 && parent.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    parent.Children.RemoveAt(random.Next(0, parent.Children.Count));
                }
                else
                {
                    var inner = CreateChild();
                    if (!parent.Children.Any(io => io.Name == inner.Name))
                    {
                        parent.Children.Add(inner);
                    }

                }

                await ReplaceOne<Parent>(parent);
            }             
        }
    }
```

I have a list of Parents and each one contains a list of Child elements. When using the c# Mongo driver to replace these parents after they have been updated by either removing or adding new Children It sometimes creates duplicates of the Child on the Mongo side despite there being no duplicates when the code calls the replace method.

I think this is something to do with the atomic sub document structure of Mongo and how it updates/replaces items. Is there a way to prevent this from creating duplicates? and if it is not happening due to the atomic nature what is causing this?
Edit:

```
    static async Task ReplaceOne<T>(T obj)
        where T : Nameable
    {
        await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name).ReplaceOneAsync(Builders<T>.Filter.Where(t => t.Name == obj.Name), obj);
    }

    static async Task Insert<T>(T obj)
    {
        await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name).InsertOneAsync(obj);
    }

    static Parent CreateParent()
    {
        var innerObjects = new List<Child>();
        for (int i = 0; i > random.Next(1, 10); i++)
        {
            innerObjects.Add(CreateChild());
        }

        return new Parent()
        {
            Name = RandomString(),
            Children = innerObjects
        };
    }

    static Child CreateChild()
    {
        return new Child()
        {
            Name = RandomString(),
            Value = RandomInt(),
            DataOne = RandomString(),
            DataTwo = RandomString(),
            DataThree = RandomDouble()
        };
    }
```

Added the replace/Insert snippets, they are using the mongo c# driver to insert into the db. The CreateParent and CreateChild just fills the objects with random relevant data.

Comment: What do the `CreateParent`, `CreateChild`, `Insert` and `ReplaceOne` methods look like?

Comment: Create parent/Child just fill the Child/Parent class with random data. Insert using Mongo c# driver to insert into mongo and replace replaces it, can post the methods as an edit tomorrow morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to guess your `RandomString()`, `RandomInt()` and `RandomDouble()` methods and I ran your project several times without cleaning the database. I could not detect any duplicates whatsoever based on the two "Name" properties (on parent and child).

I suspect your observation is somehow incorrect. In order to check if you do actually have duplicate children within the same parent you can use the following query:

```
collection.aggregate(
{
    $unwind: "$Children"
},
{
    $group:
    {
        _id:
        {
            "Name": "$Name",
            "ChildName": "$Children.Name"
        }
        , "count": { $sum: 1 }
    }
},
{
    $match:
    {
        "count": { $ne: 1 } }
    }
)
```

Comment: checked over my aggregate and looks like i had a type which was causing it to appear like there was duplicates via the count when there wasn't. Thanks